# Ecryptfs remove hard drive without logout

Tags: mount, hard-drive, home-directory, ecryptfs

As many Ubuntu users I use `ecryptfs` in order to protect encrypt my home directory.

I know that loggin into my system `ecryptfs` decrypts my files and symlinks them to the actual location of my home directory.

I was wondering what happens if someone just pulls out my hard drive from my system. Can he/she access my data becaus `ecryptfs` was not able to umount the decrypted file direcotry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite how `ecryptfs` works. Your data is stored in an encrypted, obfuscated form on disk. (see `ls -lL $HOME/.Private`) `ecryptfs` mounts a stacked filesystem on top of your `$HOME`, and decrypts the files (data and metadata) on-the-fly, as you access the files through the `ecryptfs` filesystem (which uses the underlying `ext4` (or whatever) filesystem on disk for data storage). The results of the `ecrypts` filesystem (files, metadata) exists ONLY in the virtual memory of the running system. If your disk is hot-unplugged, all that is taken away is the encrypted, obfuscated disk storage. Also, your computer will be unhappy.